# Azure devops, inherited process, cannot Add new completed state VS403093

Tags: azure-devops, agile, user-stories

When I try to add new completed state to user story or task in inherited process of my azure devops project, I get the following error :

> VS403093: Team Services currently does not support changes to
> 'Completed' category. Choose a different category.

I have looked all over the web and it seems like this is the desired behaviour as mentioned in this link, which I think is very weird.

Are there any workarounds?

I want to create a Done state for my work items, and I think that it's dumb to keep only the closed state for all completed work items since Completed fits better with tickets not with user stories in my sense...

As mentioned below, I could modify all the states except for completed
[image: VS403093]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, at this time Microsoft not allow to change or add states in Complete category.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories):

> **Completed:** Assigned to states that represent work has finished. work items whose state is in this category don't appear on the backlog and do appear in the last column of the Kanban board. Note that you can't modify states in this category nor can you add states to this category.

If you want the state "Done" you can use Scrum template (in Scrum the complete state is Done and not Closed).

Comment: is there any reason behind this decision?

Comment: @HaithemKAROUI I have no idea :(