# Azure DevOps: Change state used to determine velocity for velocity chart on dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, scrum

My team's workflow goes New -> Active -> Ready to Relearse -> Closed. Ready to Release is used after the Product Owner approves the work to go to Production. Once the work is in Production, the story is closed. We have three week sprints and release every two weeks for now.

How can I use the Ready to Release state to calculate velocity for the velocity chart on the dashboard? Using Closed state to record velocity for completed work makes it look like the team carries over work each sprint, when really it's work in Ready to Release that won't be released until 2-9 days later.

I understand there are better ways to track work that hasn't been released yet, but I inherited this team and don't want to make sweeping changes until we have improved processes that got us to this point.

I also don't want to create a PowerBI dashboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the Ready to Release state to calculate velocity for the velocity chart on the dashboard?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed**. Azure devops does not support custom state used to determine velocity for velocity chart at this moment.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bwomp bwomp. They won't even let me move a state to the Completed category. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129556/azure-devops-inherited-process-cannot-add-new-completed-state-vs403093